# I'm getting expression expected warning in my react native code

Tags: react-native

I'm learning react native and in my app.js I'm getting expression expected warning after return statement

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './app/components/Main.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      </Main>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: should be `<Main />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
import React from 'react';
import Main from './app/components/Main.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Main />
    );
  }
}
```